# How to fix system property error Java

Tags: java, exception, properties, null

I'm using the properties `-D` method to give arguments to a jar file on the command line.  Here's the code:

```
        String prop1 = "one";  

        String val1 = System.getProperty(prop1);  

        System.out.println(val1);
```

This works, but when I try to implement this in a larger program, strange things happen.  Without arguments, this will print `null`, which is fine.  But if I then do something like `boolean test = val1.equals(null);` , I get problems that don't seem to relate to the code I've provided.  Any thoughts?

Comment: That's right; the `NullPointerException` has nothing to do with system properties.

Comment: I think you want to write `boolean test = val1 == null;`

Comment: Wow, easy one for you guys, eh?!!  Thanks, I learned a lot here.  So every `null` assignment references the same object, whose value is `null`, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are encoutering a `NullPointerException` because you try to evaluate a method on a null reference. If val1 is null, you cannot invoke a method on it. If you want to test for null, you should test with `==`.

```
if (val1==null)
   // doSomething
```

or

```
if(val1!=null && val.equals("aValue")) {
    // Do something
}
```

Comment: Ahh, so every string assigned the value `null` references the same `null` object?  So, there's only one real `null` object in the universe, and all strings assigned the value of `null` reference this ubiquitous object?

Comment: This is not specific to `String`, this is valid for all objects. Only primitive types cannot be assigned `null`(you will get also a NPE if you try to).

Answer (score 2):

You are doing `null.equals(null)` if val1 is null which will cause `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
val1 == null
```

instead when comparing to `null`.

The `null` value is a reference value but does not refer to a real object (`!(null instanceof Object)`), so it has no methods, not even the `equals` method.